# How do I activate debug log in Liferay 7 CE?

Tags: tomcat8

I am installing Liferay 7 CE in existing tomcat 8 in centos 7 following this [article](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/installing-liferay-on-tomcat-8). Installations fails but the logs don't show anything specific. How do I activate debug log? Is there any guide?

Comment: Could you attach the log?

Comment: I can not access Liferay through the browser but tomcat is up. All messages are INFO. I can't see any warning or debug. So I don't think is necessary to upload the log. Just to find a way to change the log level.

Comment: Have you got an http server in front of Tomcat? Are liferay and tomcat starting successfully?

Comment: I only use tomcat and it starts with generic errors (listeners didn't start) and no other detail. Liferay is not starting.

Comment: Any exception in the logs?

Comment: No, that's why i need to enable debug log. To check for more detailed logs.

Comment: Could you check on your Liferay Home, there must be a logs folder with different and more detailed log files.

Comment: All the logs are located in tomcat/logs directory and I already checked there for errors. Unfortunately I didn't find any error but liferay is not working. That's why i need to enable debug logs to search for more detailed errors